# Check if a query was successful laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I define a query to delete a table in database. After that i want to show a message that the query was run successfully. How can I check it with an `if` statement?

```
$query = DB::table('user_users')->delete();     

return view('datenbank');
```

Comment: This query will not delete the table, [it will empty the table](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#deletes).

Comment: Sorry, i meaned that. :-D

Comment: What have you tried so far? Something like inspecting whatever `$query` contains?

Comment: When you say you "delete the table" are you meaning empty it or actually remove the table from the database?

Answer (score 6):

When you use `delete` with the query builder it will return the number of affected rows.

Your if statement would just need to look something like:

```
$query = DB::table('user_users')->delete(); 

if ($query) {
    //query successful
}
```

If you want to be more explicit you could do `if ($query > 0) {}`

If anything goes wrong with the query (an error) it will throw an `Exception` which will mean that no rows have been affected.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think the best solution is to use an if statement like this.

your code

```
$query = DB::table('user_users')->delete();     

return view('datenbank');
```

Soluction

```
$query = DB::table('user_users')->delete();
// check data deleted or not
 if ($query > 0) {
     return response()->json('202 Accepted', 202);
 } else {
     return response()->json('404 Not Found', 404);
 }
```

Comment: Out of context. May be better if we return 204 status code instead of 202.

Answer (score 0):

If the query did not execute successfully, Laravel would normally throw an error. But if you want to be really sure, you could query the table right after truncating it to make sure there is no data left.

```
DB::table('user_users')->delete();     

// Test if no records are left in the table
$success = DB::table('user_users')->count() === 0;

return view('datenbank', compact('success'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to use try catch because laravel query throw exception when some error occur...

```
$queryStatus;
try {
    DB::table('user_')->where('column',$something)->delete();
    $queryStatus = "Successful";
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $queryStatus = "Not success";
}
return view('datenbank')->with('message', $queryStatus);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do `try catch` with `DB Transaction`

```
try {
        DB::beginTransaction();

        // your code

        DB::commit();
    }catch (Exception $e) {

        DB::rollback();

        // other actions

    }
```